# How to make an element display immediately after text but remain docked to the right when text does not fit

Tags: html, css

Here is an image of what I want to achieve using CSS:

[image: The desired output: element is displayed right after the text, until the line breaks. In that case it remains docked to the right and the text is cropped]

The challenge is to display the "end" element right after the text when the text fits, but make sure it remains docked to the right when the text does not fit.

Here is the HTML:

```
<p>
This is a short text <span>end</span>
</p>

<p>
This is a very long text, very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long <span>end</span>
</p>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/b1447avy/), with some CSS (not working case 2). Basically, either I get 1 OR 2 working (using `float: right` on the "end" element), but not both at the same time.

Some constraints:

- The width of "end" may vary (it could contain any variable length text)
- The solution should fit both cases
- The HTML may be modified (please avoid tables :(
- I'm after a CSS solution -- if impossible, any JS solution should be as light as possible
- All major browsers supported (at least Firefox, Chrome, Edge latest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
p {
  width: 95vw;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.terminator {
  margin-left: 1%;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="content">This is a short text </span>
  <span class="terminator">end</span>
</p>

<p>
  <span class="content">
This is a very long text, very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long</span>
  <span class="terminator">end</span>
</p>

<p>
  <span class="content">This is a short text </span>
  <span class="terminator">a bloody hellish end</span>
</p>

<p>
  <span class="content">
This is a very long text, very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long</span>
  <span class="terminator">a bloody hellish end</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Yes, but wait: what's the "max-width: 90%" bit? Is it to leave room for "end". Remember the length of that text is variable, it could well be "a bloody hellish end"

Comment: if it is too long you have to truncate that too other wise it won't fit in a single line anyway

Comment: Actually, it works without the max-width, so I this you can remove it. Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/b1447avy/7/

Comment: consider updating your answer without the hardcoded width (see previous comment) and I'll accept it

Comment: It actually works better without the max-width. I was busy trying to find a solution with grow/ shrink and totally missed the fact that the flex property on the parent with no-wrap will try to fit every thing within bounds.

Answer (score 1):

add style to span:

```
position: sticky;
right: 0px;
```

remove from p:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: Wow I thought this was a joke! I didn't know about [position: sticky](http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky). I tried on Chrome and Google get it working as I want. Can you update the Fiddle? (I'll add a constraint to have a solution that works on all current browsers)

Comment: Pretty neat, but shame for the browser support and the ellipsis :(

Comment: sorry i deleted fiddle by mistake. here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/techLove/r6vq90pn/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand what exactly you're looking for (though I did read carefully) but this seemed to do it.

```
<div>This is very very very very very very very very long text<span>END</span></div>
<div>This is short text<span>END</span></div>
```

The span just comes after whatever text is in the wrapping div. The display is exactly what you have above. If you truncate the text, same thing.

Comment: No with my Fiddle, the "END" block disappears when the long text does not fit on the line. It doesn't look like the image in my question.

Comment: Ah ok I think I get what you're saying now. By "not fit", you mean you've absolutely sized the div containing the text. Hmm I have another idea. There's some neat CSS ways to do this but browser support is wonky.